# Best Way to reference a SQL Inner Join Query alias in MVC 5 Razor

Tags: c#-4.0, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following code and was wondering if there was any way to reference "ManagedByName" in MVC 5 Razor or if you know a work around, it would be greatly appreciated.

What I am trying to accomplish is to derive a First and Last name combined in an object or preferably "alias" that can be accessed within Razor. I need help in accomplishing this task please. I have already worked on this almost two days and I am baffled....

**In controller Class, I have the following:**

```
  public async Task<ActionResult> Details(string location)
        {

            if (location == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
          //  Contractor contractor = db.Contractors.Find(id);

            string Query = "SELECT cmb.*, dc.DeliveryCenter,c.ContractorNumber,c.SubContractor,c.FirstName,c.LastName,c.dbaBusinessName,at.AccountTitleDescription,c.Email,c.MasterContractorNumber,c.MasterContractorNumber,c.OriginalContractDate,c.IsContractSuspended" +
            " from Contractor c inner join ContractorManagedBy cmb on c.ManagedBy = cmb.ManagedBy" +
            " inner join DCLocMapping dc on c.LocationID = dc.LocationID" +
            " inner join AccountTitle at on c.AccountTitleID = at.AccountTitleID" +
            " where DeliveryCenter in (@p0) order by dc.DeliveryCenter,c.ContractorNumber" +
            " Select new Contracting { ManagedBy1 = cmb.ManagerFirstName + ' ' + cmb.ManagerLastName}";


            Contractor contractor = await db.Contractors.SqlQuery(Query, location).SingleOrDefaultAsync();

            if (contractor == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
                        return View(contractor);
        }

public class Contracting
        {
            public int iimanagedby { get; set; }
            public string ManagedByName { get; set; }
        }

public IQueryable<Contracting> TakeManagedBy()
        {
            return (from x in db.ContractorManagedBies
                     orderby x.ManagerLastName
                     select new Contracting
                     {
                         iimanagedby = x.ManagedBy,
                         ManagedByName = x.ManagerFirstName + " " + x.ManagerLastName

                     });
        }
```

**In the Razor Page, I have:**

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item...
}
```

I can get the objects from Ienumerable Model, but do not see a way to get the **ManagedByName** IQeryable name within the foreach loop as that object is not recognized. Again, any help with code example would be greatly appreciated. I am somewhat new to MVC but hope there is a way to work this solution that baffles me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend EF clases sideways by adding new properties in a matching partial class. I strongly suggest you start using EF and stop using hard-wired SQL strings:)

Just add `ManagedByName` as a property that returns the other two names joined and use that like any other property in the view.

```
public partial class YourEFModelClassNameHere
{
   public string ManagedByName
   {
      get
      {
          return this.ManagerFirstName + " " + this.ManagerLastName;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional insight. I will see if I can work a solution with the info. that you provided and will let you know.

Comment: Actually, now that I look at it, where I am stuck is how to call the value of this EF object in the same page where I reference another @model entity at the top of the page?

Comment: For example, I have: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SomeID within the page, with the @model IEnumerable<DDB.Ctr> at the top of the page but how can I call the additional EF object "sideways" as you say so that it renders in the foreach loop?

Comment: Partial classes are effectively the same class. Just make sure the new class has the exact same namespace as the original. The new property then just exists on `Ctr` (which I assume is your class name).

Comment: Okay, this might sound like a dumb question but do I add this code that you provided as part of the controller or as a ViewModel? I am not sure where to put it so that it properly executes. Or should I edit the EF class directly?

Comment: Never edit the EF class directly as changes will be lost (it is generated). Not in controller and not in viewmodel. Put it in a separate class file and make sure the namespaces matches the EF class. I generally put EF models and extensions into their own library file to keep it all together, but anywhere in the project will do for now. if you have any problems, Google "C# partial classes".